# randomForest - logical comparison failing when data value equals split value

Tags: r, random-forest

I have been working on a project that has required digging into the individual tree predictions from a randomForest.  I have a randomForest object and I used the predict method on new data to create the object that contains the individual tree predictions as well as the overall forest prediction.

I found that there were instances where the value that defines a split was the same as the value of the data.  In such cases, the algorithm should be choosing the left daughter to continue, but in these cases, it was choosing the right daughter.  In other words, the test of data_value <= split_value, was returning FALSE instead of TRUE.

```
# rf2 is a RandomForest object
# get the 56th tree out of the RandomForest
> t56 <- getTree(rf2,k=56,labelVar=T)

# find the value of the split point for node 448
> t56[448,"split point"]
[1] 5.53

> t56[448,"split point"] == 5.53
[1] FALSE

> t56[448,"split point"] >5.53
[1] FALSE

> t56[448,"split point"] <5.53
[1] TRUE

> t56[448,"split point"] <5.529999999999999
[1] FALSE

> t56[448,"split point"] <5.5299999999999999
[1] TRUE

# value of the data used to make the split
> dat[,"V1"]
[1] 5.53

> dat[,"V1"]<= t56[448,"split point"]
[1] FALSE
```

Has anyone seen anything like this?

Thanks

Additional investigation:

```
 > options(digits=15)
 > t56[448,"split point"] 
 [1] 5.53
```

Also verified in the R-Studio viewer for the t56 object that the value for split point is 5.53000000000000e+00.

If there is some other way to show that value is not exactly 5.53, I'd be very interested in it.

Comment: Are you certain this isn't simply a case of not understanding floating point comparisons?

Comment: Could be.  Can you elaborate?  It is disconcerting because in some cases the competing final predictions are opposites...one path yields 0 and the other yields 1.

Comment: Hard to elaborate on my phone. But you seem to be assuming that simply because 5.53 is printed on the console that the underlying value is EXACTLY 5.53, rather than trusting that the authors of a well used piece of numerical software haven't messed up simple comparisons of numbers.

Comment: Ok but exporting to pmml contains the exact 5.53 so uding the pmml to make a prediction outside of R will be incorrect

Comment: Then perhaps what you've found is a bug in the pmml exporter. But at least put in some effort to verify that the split value isn't exactly 5.53. ie options(digits = )